# Apenas uma linha como true, MYSQL - Codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

Olá!

Visto que tenho a seguinte tabela:

```html
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tb_conta`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tb_conta` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `nome` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `tipo` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    `padrao` BIT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1, 
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE=InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Eu preciso fazer com que independente da quantidade de linhas gravadas nesta tabela, exista somente um resultado no campo `padrao`, cujo valor seja igual a `true`

Tanto em nova inserção, quando na atualização.

**Cenário:**
Se ao inserir um novo registro e o valor do campo `padrao` seja igual a `true`, então automaticamente todos os outros valores já registrado na tabela, passem a ser `false`, o mesmo vale para `updates`.

**Funções para Add e Update**

```
// add
public function add($dados)
{       
    $conta = [
        'nome'   => $dados->nome,
        'tipo'   => $dados->tipo,
        'padrao' => $dados->padrao,
    ];
    $this->db->insert($this->tabela, $conta);
}

// edit 
public function edit($where, $dados)
{     
    $conta = [
        'nome'   => $dados->nome,
        'tipo'   => $dados->tipo,
        'padrao' => $dados->padrao,
    ];
    $this->db->update($this->tabela, $conta, $where);
    return $this->db->affected_rows();
}
```

**queries:**

```
INSERT INTO `tb_conta` (`nome`, `tipo`, `padrao`) VALUES ('Teste', '1', 1)
UPDATE `tb_conta` SET `nome` = 'Caixa Interno', `tipo` = '1', `padrao` = 1 WHERE `id` = '1'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi criando uma nova função e colocando uma condição nas funções:

**função criada**

```
// mark_all_false
public function mark_all_false()
{
    $this->db->where('padrao', true)->update($this->tabela, array('padrao' => false));
}
```

**Condição criada**

```
if ($dados->padrao == true)
{
    $this->mark_all_false();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Crie uma trigger para agir antes do select para **update** todos que estao como true assim quando inserir o novo ele vai vir como TRUE.

CREATE TRIGGER BEFORE INSERT
ON Tb_conta
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE tb_conta SET padrao = false WHERE padrao = true;
END$

Comment: Não entendi como aplicar na função de alteração

Comment: Esse comando você vai rodar direto no seu banco de dados, e não deixá-lo no código,

Comment: Ah sim, entendi, eu tambem vi outra forma de fazer diretamente no código